# php while loop inside while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Having some problems with while loop inside another while loop

first while loop is fetching main images of the product from My SQL DB table while the second while loop is fetching other screenshots of the main product.

Here is my problem that I cannot figure out, the script is working as it should when I have only one result from DB, but if there is some multiple main products than it is failing to fetch main image of the product and its additional screenshots.

Here is my script:

```
<?
if ($free_pr_module_2 == 1) {
print<<<END
<div class="bonus">
<div class="specs-top mult">Featured $mult_pr_title</div>

END;

// multiple product image
 $mult_query = 'SELECT * FROM Files WHERE pageID = :id';
 $res = $db->prepare($mult_query);
 $res->execute(array(':id' => $pid));
while ($info = $res -> fetch()){
    $path_to_images = $image_path.$info['ImagePath'].DS;
    $mult_image_link = '<a href="'.$path_to_images.$info['templImage_lg'].'" rel="prettyPhoto[mu]" title="'.$info['templateTitle'].'"><img src="'.$path_to_images.$info['templateImage'].'" alt="'.$info['templateTitle'].' Screenshot'.'" width="'.$info['templimgwidth'].'" height="'.$info['templimgheight'].'" title="'.$info['templateTitle'].'"></a>';
    $mult_templTitle = '<h3>'.$info['templateTitle'].'</h3>';
    $mult_templText = $info['add_product_description'];
    $mult_templVersion = '<span class="tech"><b>VERSION</b> '.$info['templateVersion'].'</span>';
    $mult_templLicense = '<span class="tech"><b>LICENSE</b> '.$info['templLicense'].'</span>';
    $mult_download_but_path = SITE_DOMAIN.DS.DIR_FILES.DS;
    $mult_file_urlid = $info['urlid'];
    $mult_xls_button = ($info['xls'] == 1) ? '<div class="bb">
 <div class="bbl">Excel 2003(XP)<br><span>File: XLS</span></div>
 <div class="bb_button"><a class="bb_xls" href="'.$mult_download_but_path.'xls.php?urlid='.$mult_file_urlid.'" rel="nofollow" onClick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'Downloads\', \'XLS\', this.href.substr(29)]); user_notice(this,\'\'); return false;">Download</a></div>
</div>' : ('');
    $mult_xlsx_button = ($info['xlsx'] == 1) ? '<div class="bb">
 <div class="bbl">Excel 2007 +<br><span>File: XLSX</span></div>
 <div class="bb_button"><a class="bb_xlsx" href="'.$mult_download_but_path.'xlsx.php?urlid='.$mult_file_urlid.'" rel="nofollow" onClick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'Downloads\', \'XLSX\', this.href.substr(29)]); user_notice(this,\'\'); return false;">Download</a></div>
</div>' : ('');
    $mult_ots_button = ($info['ots'] == 1) ? '<div class="bb">
 <div class="bbl">OpenOffice<br><span>File: OTS</span></div>
 <div class="bb_button"><a class="bb_ots" href="'.$mult_download_but_path.'ots.php?urlid='.$mult_file_urlid.'" rel="nofollow" onClick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'Downloads\', \'OTS\', this.href.substr(29)]); user_notice(this,\'\'); return false;">Download</a></div>
</div>' : ('');
    $mult_gdocs_button = ($info['gdocs'] == NULL) ? '' : '<div class="bb">
 <div class="bbl">Google Docs<br></div>
 <div class="bb_button"><a class="bb_gdt" href="'.$info['gdocs'].'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" onClick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'Downloads\', \'GDT\', this.href.substr(40)]);">Preview</a></div>
</div>';
    $mult_numbers_button = ($info['numbers'] == 1) ? '<div class="bb">
 <div class="bbl">Mac Numbers<br><span>File: NUMBERS</span></div>
 <div class="bb_button"><a class="bb_mac" href="'.$mult_download_but_path.'num.php?urlid='.$mult_file_urlid.'" rel="nofollow" onClick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'Downloads\', \'MCN\', this.href.substr(40)]); user_notice(this,\'\'); return false;">Download</a></div>
</div>' : ('');


print<<<END

<div class="mult_cont">
<div class="ss_left">

$mult_image_link

<div class="screnshot">
<span class="enlarge">1</span>
END;

// aditional images
$mult_main_image = "SELECT * FROM simages WHERE parentpageID = :id and main_img_show = '2'";
$res = $db->prepare($mult_main_image);
$res->execute(array(':id' => $pid));

$mult_num = 2;
while ($info = $res -> fetch()){
    $mult_post_img_link = $path_to_images.$info['main_img'];
    $mult_prphoto_id = $info['prphoto_id'];
    $mult_post_img_title = $info['main_img_title'];
    $mult_link_l = ($mult_num++);

print<<<END
<a href="$mult_post_img_link" class="enlarge" rel="prettyPhoto[$mult_prphoto_id]" title="$mult_post_img_title">$mult_link_l</a> 

END;
}

print<<<END
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>

$mult_templTitle
$mult_templText
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="download">
<div class="mult_spec">
$mult_templVersion
$mult_templLicense
</div>

$mult_xls_button

$mult_xlsx_button

$mult_ots_button

$mult_gdocs_button

$mult_numbers_button

<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
END;
}

print<<<END
</div>
END;

}else
echo '';

?>
```

Please be patients with me since I am only learning PHP/My SQL and all this is practically my first attempt to create something useful for my site.

Your help is highly appriciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting you variables. Change `$res` and `$info` from inner loop to something else, eg. `$res2`.

Comment: Thanks, you were right, worked like it was suppose to, thanks for you quick anwer